# cmake не включает директорию

Tags: c++, cmake

Пробую собрать проект со следующей структурой:

```
.
├── build
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── src
    └── main.cpp
```

Cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(Test LANGUAGES CXX)
target_include_directories(test
    PRIVATE
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
)

add_executable(test)
target_sources(test PRIVATE main.cpp)
```

Получаю ошибку - Cannot specify include directories for target "test" which is not built by
this project.
Почему? Я ведь я ведь указываю где лежать *.cpp файлы - почему он не видит включенную директорию?

Comment: `target_include_directories` передают компилятору ключик `-I`, который указывает компилятору, где искать хедеры... к тому где cmake будет искать cpp это не имеет ни какого отношения...

Comment: в добавку к предыдущему комменту хочу заметить, что инструкции target_* лучше включать после объявления этого самого таргета.